# How to connect a webservice to get currency values in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, httpwebrequest, currency

I would like to get values of currencies on my iphone application whe it starts. 
How to do it? what webservice? I found a code in php using google request as "1 USD FOR EURO" that returns the currency value (try this [link text](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=1+usd+in+euro&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=)) but how to get the returning value in OjC and put it into a variable? thank you

Comment: See this q&a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192025/where-can-i-find-updated-live-exchange-rates/6958579#6958579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Now I'm studing sdk in orther to know how to read xml files

Answer (score 0):

The exchange rate is not a world constant - it varies from one exchange office to another. Try finding a bank, or some kind of a financial institution, that publishes their rates as a Web service.

Comment: I found this www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml